# Set only properties that don't exist

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to update a node from an input map in my cypher query, but I only want to set properties that don't already exist in the node (whereas `=` overrides all the node's properties and `+=` overrides all the properties that appear in the map).

For example if I have a node `(n {key: "abc", prop1: "value"})` and I have a map to update with:

```
WITH {key: "abc", prop1: "othervalue", prop2: "newvalue"}) AS update_map
```

I would like an operation that would match by `key`, and update `prop2`, without overriding `prop1`, so the result would be: `(n {key: "abc", prop1: "value", prop2: "newvalue"})`.

My current approach was to go key-by-key:

```
UNWIND KEYS(update_map) AS update_map_key
MATCH (n {key: update_map.key})
WHERE n[update_map_key] IS NULL
SET n[update_map_key] = update_map[update_map_key]
```

This looks great (maybe except the search-for-the-node-per-key), but unfortunately doesn't work because though you can fetch a property with variable name using the `[]` syntax, you can't update it.

Any ideas? Running on Neo4j 2.3.7 if it matters.

Answer (score 1):

I think APOC will work here: apoc.create.setProperty( [node,id,ids,nodes], key, value) - sets the given property on the node(s), though I'm not sure in which version it was added. See: 
[Neo4j: Dynamically add property/Set dynamic property](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2016/10/27/neo4j-dynamically-add-property/)

Comment: Much appreciated, but it seems like it's only for Neo4j 3 (requiring user-defined procedures). Do you happen to have a solution for Neo4j 2.3?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It's a 3.x feature.